# Can't create a PushNotification instance

Tags: android, push-notification, pusher, android-push-notification

I signed up for a Pusher/Beams account for my Android app. I was able to set it up no problem. But when I went to simply create a new pushnotification instance I ran into an error. The documentation from **Pusher** uses this code:

```
String instanceId = "YOUR_INSTANCE_ID_HERE";
String secretKey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE";

PushNotifications pushNotifications = new PushNotifications(instanceId,secretKey);
```

However when I literally copy and paste that into Android Studios I get an error saying PushNotifications does not accept Strings. I am baffled as to why this is happening. 
Here is my code:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotifications;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String instanceId = "YOUR_INSTANCE_ID_HERE";
    String secretKey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE";

    PushNotifications pushNotifications = new PushNotifications(instanceId, secretKey);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "my_instance_id");
        PushNotifications.subscribe("hello");
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass string as first argument to [PushNotification](https://docs.pusher.com/beams/reference/android#start-beams) constructor. You are passing incorrect parameters.

Current is:

```
PushNotifications pushNotifications = new PushNotifications(instanceId, secretKey);
```

Change to:

```
PushNotificationsInstance pushNotifications =
    new PushNotificationsInstance(getApplicationContext(), instanceId);
```

It will work.

Check here for more information : https://docs.pusher.com/beams/reference/android#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `PushNotificationsInstance pushNotifications = new PushNotificationsInstance (instanceId, secretKey);`